# Falcon cluster entity submission

Tags: falcon, apache-falcon

I am getting error when I try to submit my cluster entity in Falcon.

Output error on submission:

```
org.apache.falcon.client.FalconCLIException: Bad Request;Cluster definition missing required namenode credential property: dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal
        at org.apache.falcon.client.FalconCLIException.fromReponse(FalconCLIException.java:44)
        at org.apache.falcon.client.FalconClient.checkIfSuccessful(FalconClient.java:1172)
        at org.apache.falcon.client.FalconClient.sendEntityRequestWithObject(FalconClient.java:694)
        at org.apache.falcon.client.FalconClient.submit(FalconClient.java:323)
        at org.apache.falcon.cli.FalconCLI.entityCommand(FalconCLI.java:364)
        at org.apache.falcon.cli.FalconCLI.run(FalconCLI.java:183)
        at org.apache.falcon.cli.FalconCLI.main(FalconCLI.java:133)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue I resolved with the following. You can add following tag to your entity xml just before the closing tags of feed or cluster

```
<properties>
  <property name="dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal" value="nn/master.example.com"/>
 </properties>
```

In the above master.example.com is your hostname where name node exists.

Answer (score 0):

Is your cluster kerberized?
Then better check, http://falcon.apache.org/Security.html

- Authentication Methods
- Authentication Configuration
- Authorization Configuration